# Not able to iterate over a list in python

Tags: python, list

Hi i am not able to convert my string separated by "space" into a list from a for loop.
Displays runtime error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sorted'

```
#The code is to get the second highest number

n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())   # this is a string
arr_list = []
for i in range(n):
    arr_list = arr_list.append(arr)
    arr_list = arr_list.sorted()
    arr_set = set(arr_list)
    if len(arr_list) > 1:
        print(list(arr_set)[-2])
    else:
        print(arr_list[0])
```

Comment: `arr = list(map(int, input().split()))` should do... `arr` is now already a list.

Comment: Thanx, But its not working. Tried already

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

`arr_list.append(arr)` appends `arr` to `arr_list` and returns `None`, hence:

`arr_list = arr_list.append(arr)` **==>** `arr_list = None`

`arr_list.sorted() => None.sorted()` **==>** `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sorted'`

Also, to sort a list with `sorted`, use `sorted(list)` instead of `list.sorted()`.

To convert your string to a list, you should do:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split())) # this is a list
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of errors, but it can be reduced to:

```
arr = sorted(set(map(int, input('Enter space-separated numbers: ').split())))
if len(arr) > 1:
    print(arr[-2])
else:
    print(arr[0])
```

`map()` returns a map object.  `set` creates the unique values from iterating the map.  `sorted()` puts them in order.

The original error in your code was:

```
arr_list = arr_list.append(arr)
arr_list = arr_list.sorted()
```

`arr_list.append()` is an in-place operation and returns `None`, which is then assigned to `arr_list`.  `None` doesn't have a `.sorted()` method.

Comment: Hi, I want use (n) because i only want "n" number elements to be restricted.

Comment: @shivam That wasn't clear from your question but I'm sure you can adapt this to your needs. Just slice the input if you only want n of them with [:n]